# How to pause, cancel or delete a scheduled CiviMail mailing

Tags: civimail

I suspect I'm missing something obvious here... but I've just spent 30mins googling without success.

So... if you've scheduled a mailing in Civicrm, how can you pause, delete or cancel it?

On the main search screen for mailings, https://druyoga.com/civicrm/mailing/browse/scheduled?reset=1&scheduled=true, you can search for various mailing statuses, including paused and cancelled.

But I can't see a way to change a mailing's status to cancelled or paused.

Thanks for any ideas.

We're using drupal 7.54 and Civicrm 4.6.24

Answer (score 4):

If you search for mailings (Search>Find Mailings) and check 'Scheduled' when results com up on the far right there is an option to 'Cancel' under the 'more' menu.

I assume you can pause by searching for 'running' mailings and looking under the 'more' menu but I can't verify as I don't have a running mailing right now.

Comment: I agree with your Cancel but have never known a 'pause' was possible.

Comment: Wow - I looked for that option and didn't see it. I did a hard refresh of my pages and there it is... So this must have been a temporary js glitch in our sites. 
Thanks for taking the time to give the answer..... 

Having answered this though, is there a way to edit the Mailing in any way once it's scheduled? Or is the only option to 're-use' and then cancel the initial version?

Comment: If the CRON job has not yet run you can cancel the mailing and then re-use.

Comment: I think the only scenario a pause would work is if you had a big mailing and were throttling the delivery. So if it was a 10,000 recipient mailing and you set it to only send 2,000 each time the job runs that is where I think the pause option would come in. Never tried this just thinking out loud.